# glDrawArrays not drawing anything

Tags: c++, opengl

glDrawArrays isn't drawing anything to the screen, but drawing using glVertex2d seems to work.

I'm on OpenGL 3.0. My hunch is that it's an issue with the shaders, but because they both compile fine, I can't figure out what the problem is. Anyone have any idea what could be causing the issue?

```
   // OpenGL.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
    //

    #include "stdafx.h"

    #define GLEW_STATIC
    #include <GL\glew.h>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <GLFW\glfw3.h>

    using namespace std;

    const char* vertex_shader_data = 
        "#version 150\n"
        "in vec2 position;"
        "void main(){"
        "gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);"
        "}";

    const char* fragment_shader_data = 
        "#version 150\n"
        "out vec4 outColor;"
        "void main(){"
        "outColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);"
        "}";


    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])

{

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glfwInit();

    GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "OpenGL Fun", NULL, NULL);

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glewInit();

    GLuint buffer;

    float vertices[] = { 0.0f, 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f };

    glEnable(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);

    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);


    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    GLuint vertexshader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint fragmentshader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    glShaderSource(vertexshader, 1, &vertex_shader_data, NULL);
    glShaderSource(fragmentshader, 1, &fragment_shader_data, NULL);

    glCompileShader(vertexshader);
    glCompileShader(fragmentshader);

    GLint vstatus;
    GLint fstatus;

    glGetShaderiv(vertexshader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &vstatus);
    glGetShaderiv(fragmentshader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &fstatus);

#pragma region Shader Compilation Test
    if(!((vstatus == GL_TRUE) && (fstatus == GL_TRUE))) {

        char info[512];

        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexshader, 512, NULL, info);

        for(int i=0; i<512; i++) {

            cout << info[i];

        }

        glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentshader, 512, NULL, info);

        for(int i=0; i<512; i++) {

            cout << info[i];

        }

    }  
#pragma endregion


    GLuint shaderprogram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderprogram, vertexshader);
    glAttachShader(shaderprogram, fragmentshader);

    glBindFragDataLocation(shaderprogram, 0, "outColor");

    glLinkProgram(shaderprogram);

    glUseProgram(shaderprogram);

    GLuint pos_attribute = glGetAttribLocation(vertexshader, "position");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(pos_attribute);

    glVertexAttribPointer(pos_attribute, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);


    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {

        glClearColor( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        /*
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex2d(0.0f, 0.5f);
        glVertex2d(-0.5f, -0.5f);
        glVertex2d(0.5f, -0.5f);
        glEnd();*/

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        glfwPollEvents();

    }


    glfwTerminate();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the error state after each gl call? You would be surprised how useful gl debugging can actually be.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me track down the problem. I was getting an "GL_INVALID_OPERATION" error after the call to glGetAttribLocation. I was passing the vertexshader as the first argument when I should have been passing in the shader program.

Comment: Good - glad it helped. I know it is a pain to include them after each call. What I normally do is create a macro and append it after each call. This way I can disable the macro when I disable debug.